# Parcel plugin not working: returns string of path instead of string of contents

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I'm using Parceljs and I'm trying to load a GLSL shader as plaintext. I've installed both `parcel-plugin-glsl` and `parcel-plugin-shader-loader`, but both are not working.

I import them in my .js file like this:

`import vertexShader from "./vertex-shaders/basic.glsl";
console.log(vertexShader);`

According to the documentation I should now receive the contents of the file as text, but when I log to the console I just get the path to the file (`/dist/823ef3822e0a8f71abe50187f7dc2e79.glsl`).

I've installed the plugin using `npm install parcel-plugin-glsl --save-dev`, Parcel should handle the rest.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So the issue was resolved for me. It seems editing the shaderfiles and re-saving them resolved the issue.